# Unable to open select the time for a timepicker using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I saw that timepicker :

[Timepicker CSS](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/timepicker/)

So I tried to implement that, they told that the code is the following :

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="timepicker relative form-floating mb-3 xl:w-96" data-mdb-with-icon="false" id="input-toggle-timepicker">
    <input type="text"
      class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
      placeholder="Select a date" data-mdb-toggle="input-toggle-timepicker" />
    <label for="floatingInput" class="text-gray-700">Select a time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I tried to implement that in a codesandbox code project :

[My CodeSandBoxProject](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-14ygsl?file=/src/App.js)

with that code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <div
        class="timepicker relative form-floating mb-3 xl:w-96"
        data-mdb-with-icon="false"
        id="input-toggle-timepicker"
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
          placeholder="Select a date"
          data-mdb-toggle="input-toggle-timepicker"
        />
        <label for="floatingInput" class="text-gray-700">
          Select a time
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But When I click on the timepicker I got nothing instead of I should have that :

[image: The expected result]

I don't understand why I do not get that. Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Your CodeSandbox is using a very old version of Tailwind (1.0.4), so you might upgrade to the latest. It also does not appear that you've installed Tailwind Elements, which is needed for the timepicker styles. See: https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/